# Windows Gadgets & Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am creating a Vista Gadget and I haven't been able to get JQuery to work. I have tried a few very simple calls like this:

```
$(function() {
      $('a').click(function() {
          $('#box').html("test");
      });
});
```

I know you can use JavaScript so it doesn't make much sense to me why you wouldn't be able to use a library.

Does anyone know if any examples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Here](http://arsecandle.org/twadget/) is a widget for vista done with jquery.
Might help you.

Above link is dead - here is another https://code.google.com/archive/p/timetablegadget/source/default/source

Comment: cheers! Looked around for some examples but I couldn't fine any!

Comment: Link is dead. Repost with details?

Comment: @KarolLewandowski did you look https://code.google.com/archive/p/timetablegadget/source/default/source

Comment: It'd be better to link to this URL in answer. It was natural for me to check only Source tab and browse code there.

Comment: @Karol you really think I am gonna go through all my answers checking links? This answer was 2008.....

Comment: No, I don't, really ;-) I updated link in your answer and I think that you could do this. My update have to be reviewed and author's not. Greetings.